# How to change an instance variable that contains a changed instance variable

Tags: java, oop

How come setWav doesn't change the `wav` in `wav + " " + "Grapes"`? Do I have to create a set method for add if I want it to output `Oranges? Grapes`?

**EDIT**: Thanks everyone for the help, much appreciated.

```
package javaapplication1;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        NewClass object1 = new NewClass();
        System.out.println(object1.getAdd());
        object1.setWav("Oranges?");
        System.out.println(object1.getAdd());    


    }
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

> Burgers Grapes
>
> Burgers Grapes

---

```
package javaapplication1;

public class NewClass 
{
    private String wav;
    private String add;

    public NewClass()
    {
        wav = "Burgers";
        add = wav + " " + "Grapes";       

    }

    public void setWav(String wav)
    {
        this.wav = wav;        
    }
    public String getWav()
    {
        return wav;
    }

    public String getAdd()
    {
        return add;
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getAdd` method returns `add`. You set the value of `add` in the `NewClass` constructor but nowhere else, hence it remains unchanged even when you change `wav` (these two variables are not related in any way, changing one will not effect the other). You can try this:

```
public void setWav(String wav) {
    this.wav = wav;  
    add = wav + " " + "Grapes";  // i.e. add = wav + " Grapes";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't refresh `add` when you call `setWav`. Copy this line from the ctor to the setter:

```
add = wav + " " + "Grapes";
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 2):

In your example the constructor is responsible for updating "add". But the problem is that its only invoked once, which is when the class is instantiated.

It happens on this line:
    NewClass object1 = new NewClass();

You could change setWav into this:

```
public void setWav(String wav)
{
    this.wav = wav;
    this.add = wav + " " + "Grapes";
}
```

This way it would update add every time setWav is called.